# where/ how can I get the selenium server source code used to build 2.0b3

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to apply this bug fix http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=11856 to the selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar.

Does anyone know where I can get the source code?  The jar only contains class files.

Or if there are alternate ways of getting what I need, please do tell.

Thanks,
-Denali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to check it out from SVN:

Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:
Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ selenium-read-only

I am not entirely sure how this project branches their code, but I assume it would be a branch in the project for a release.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that.  From here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/  I looked at both branches and tags, but I don't see anything for the main 2.0b3 release.  If there was a way to find the svn revision for the 2.0b3 release then I could pull from that, but I don't what that is, or how to find it.

Comment: I would assume 2.0b3 is selenium-2.0-beta-3 as listed in the tagged version.  You should be able to checkout a tagged version, I can't seem to reach the server now.